# How do they search inside a string

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, string

What is the most efficient way to do this? There must be some better method other than brute force.

Comment: Check Boyers-moore algorithm. It is clever and nice ... and very easy to implement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on length of string, size of alphabet and whether repeated searching: Knuth-Morris-Pratt, Rabin-Karp, etc.

See [String searching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm)

[Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/kmpen.htm)

[Rabin-Karp algorithm](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/algs4/53substring/RabinKarp.java.html)